# LinqtoSql - FirstOrDefault - How do I test for default returned

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using the `FirstOrDefault<T>()` method to return an object from a Linq2Sql query. I then set an object to be equal to the returned value.

how do I test if the default has been returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If T is a non-primitive data type I believe the default value will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I originally thought, but I seemed to be getting a new object of the type being returned. Think I had some rogue data returning an object. You are absolutely right though thanks.

Answer (score 3):

using the comparison with default(T)